# Converting row values to column using pd.pivot gives index value error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert row values to column names using pivot. I get the error `'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'`. When i use pivot_table all the values are assigned 1 instead of the actual value.

Below is my data frame

```
data={ 'EID':['1234','1234','1234','1234','1235','1235','1235','1235'],
'Question':['First Name','Last Name','Gender','City','First Name','Last Name','Gender'],
'Answer':['Ren','Lyke','Male','Chicago','Tony','Ricchio','Male','Sydney']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

i get Value error when i use the below code.
    `df_transpose=df.pivot(index='EID',columns='Question',values='Answer'`)

Using pivot_table give me 1 as row values.

```
df_transpose=df.pivot_table(index='EID',columns='Question',values='Answer', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))

df_transpose=pd.DataFrame(df_transpose.to_records())
```

When i created a pivot table in excel it worked fine.

Output:
[image]

How do i make sure i get the exact dataframe that i looking for?

Comment: Well, `df.pivot(index='EID', columns='Question', values='Answer')` works just fine given your sample (or it would - if you had another `'City'` in your Question column so it actually had the right number of elements but...)

Comment: @JonClements for this data it is working fine when the rows are over 4k. I am getting the error. That is the challenge.

Comment: Right... so what about `df.pivot_table(index='EID', columns='Question', values='Answer', aggfunc='first')` ?

Comment: You might want to check what your duplicates are though using something like: `df[df.duplicated(subset=['EID', 'Question'], keep=False)]`

Comment: @JonClements, due to few questions being repeated it was causing the issue.